# Pleo LifeOS toolsuite

Tags: embedded

Does anybody know of any tool suites that are still available for Pleo LifeOS (1.0 or 1.1)? Supposedly, there was a tool chain for Pawn at some time, but that seems not to be available anymore. Or is it? Any other (true) programming APIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post on the BobThePleo forums](http://bobthepleo.com/forums/index.php?topic=360.0) seems to be the most thorough answer I could find with a bit of searching.  The short form is that the official Pawn-based "Pleo Development Kit" (PDK) was never made publicly available before the company went bankrupt, and there don't seem to be any bootleg copies around either.  However, the company has been purchased ([press release](http://www.robotsrule.com/pleo/2009/06/pleos-back-jetta-company-limited.html)) by the company that did the initial manufacturing, and apparently they plan to release the PDK at some point.  So this isn't so much a "not available anymore" as "not ever available but might be in the future".

Meanwhile, the [How do I program the Pleo's behavior?](http://pleohq.com/faq/how-do-i-program-pleos-behavior/) FAQ entry is still up, and points to [Yet Another Pleo Tool (YAPT)](http://www.aibohack.com/pleo/yapt.htm) and [the MySkit Performance Editor](http://www.dogsbodynet.com/myskit/index.html) as third-party tools.  YAPT appears to be a sort of high-level "do this stock action when that happens" tool, whereas MySkit provides methods to do what looks like full editing of the possible motions; they seem to both be necessary to create a full "personality".  However, they don't allow full programming; it's strictly a single-level response to stimulus.

That appears to be about the extent of things, as best I can tell.